# How to populate input type(text box) and label from Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

i want to show(render) text box from the database , i have following fields in the database like **controLabel** and **controlType** having values **label** and **text** respectivaly... I mean i want to show on the html page one label and one textbox those types are fetched from Database , Any idea how can i achieve this... I am doing project in the Asp.net Mvc ,, i will prefer to do this in ajax, jabascript or jquery ...

Comment: WOW. Talk about a vague question. Since you didn't provide any information about the language or really much of anything you aren't likely to get much of an answer. Generally speaking the process is: pull the data from the database, then set the text property of your label and textbox with that data.

Comment: sorry man i update the question as well as tag... @SeanLange

Comment: what is this @KidBilly :/

Comment: no man i doesnt want the data in text box i want to render textbox @SeanLange

Comment: So you are wanting to dynamically add controls to the page based on information you find in the database? Look at Page.Controls.Add

Comment: yes correct man,, Page.Controls.Add what is this can you tell me plz ? @SeanLange

Comment: Here try this link. http://bit.ly/WfLcPz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60627/discussion-between-jot-dhaliwal-and-sean-lange).

Comment: @SeanLange i have completed the task with help of javascript....

Comment: Awesome glad you were able to get it working.

Comment: i play a trick check the model.property in view and if there is textbox in that i simply append a textbox @SeanLange